# Difference between two functions that reverse a linked list...Why does one work and the other doesn't?

Tags: reverse, singly-linked-list

Below the linked list comment description are two functions that are supposed to reverse a singly linked list. The first one is correct and the 2nd one is wrong. My question is what is the difference between the two? In my eyes I feel like they are doing the exact same thing. I know the difference is in one line, I just don't know what is different in that line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
/*
  Reverse a linked list and return pointer to the head
  The input list will have at least one element  
  Node is defined as 
  struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
  }
*/
```

CORRECT IMPLEMENTATION:

```
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        return head;
    }
    else {
        Node* blah = Reverse(head->next);
        head->next->next = head;
        head->next = NULL;
        return blah;
    }
}
```

INCORRECT IMPLEMENTATION:

```
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        return head;
    }
    else {
        Node* blah = Reverse(head->next);
        blah->next = head;
        head->next = NULL;
        return blah;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a piece of paper, draw a list with a few elements, and run your algorithms by hand. You'll see *what* happens, and *then* you'll understand why one is not correct.

Comment: I tried doing this on paper and I still end up puzzled. I am puzzled because    I believe the variables "blah" and "head->next" are pointing to the exact same address in memory. So I think blah = head->next, and so I don't see how "head->next->next = head" is any different from "blah->next = head".

Comment: When you run your algorithm, is it different, or not ?
Hint : was  the content of `head->next` modified by the `reverse` function ?

Comment: Ah I got it. blah is pointing to the same node at every return, whereas head->next is traversing backwards at every return. Thanks!